# How to query age of a work item in TFS?

Tags: tfs

Lets say, in TFS 2013, age of a work item can be calculated by the number of days between `Created Date` and `Resolved Date`. I need to write such query in TFS portal and plot a chart against it. I know how to plot the chart but I have no idea how to write such query in portal as I see no way of doing this.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't calculate one work item's age via using work item query. Instead, you need to first calculate work item age with reporting or TFS API, then create chart based on these available work item age data.

Also have a check on this link which discusses a similar issue: [How to get the time between two TFS Work Item States in SSAS (or any other report)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706443/how-to-get-the-time-between-two-tfs-work-item-states-in-ssas-or-any-other-repor)