# Team Foundation Server 2015 (TFS) Query

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

It is possible to create a query in FTS to show the NUMBER OF DAYS in a feature while it was in 'Progress'?

I tried to find the start and end date and then calculate the number of days in-between but I don't think TFS allows any mathematical calculations.

Would anyone please be able to shed some light if this is possible and if so how it can be achieved.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, we can't calculate the work item's age using work item query. But you can try to calculate work item age with reporting or TFS API, then create chart based on these available work item age data.

For getting the work item's age with Custom Reports you can reference these articles:

- https://roadtoalm.com/2012/02/22/using-custom-reports-in-tfs-part-1-introduction-in-tfs-data/
- http://tfsdwreporting.blogspot.com/2009/11/creating-tfs-work-item-aging-report.html

And another similar thread talking about the work item age for your reference:
[How to get the time between two TFS Work Item States in SSAS (or any other report)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706443/how-to-get-the-time-between-two-tfs-work-item-states-in-ssas-or-any-other-repor)

Besides, you can try querying from database directly to get the start date, then calculate the number of days for the work items with 'In Progress' state, something like this:

```
SELECT 
       System_WorkItemType
      ,System_Title
      ,System_State
      ,System_CreatedDate
      ,DateDiff("DAY",System_CreatedDate,GETDATE()) as Age

 FROM [Tfs_Warehouse].[dbo].[DimWorkItem]
 WHERE System_State = 'In Progress'
```

[image]

Comment: @MileMile Have you resolved your issue by this workaround? Any update for this?